# Does Every .NET Language have their own built in library or they follows BCL (Framework Base Class Library) of .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

Actually, I have doubt, As Microsoft claim that .net support around 60+ programming languages, so my question is that do all those Programming languages have their own libraries along with the base class library or they all consume the base class library.

if they are having their own libraries than what is the use of BCL

if they are using BCL then all those languages will have different syntax.

Comment: All the .Net-supporting languages compile to the Common Intermediate Language, and that includes all the BCL assemblies. So regardless of the source language, all the assemblies are in CIL and can (generally) use types from other CIL assemblies.

Comment: While early on Microsoft did encourage development of compilers for various languages to .NET, you'll find that today the supported languages are mostly C#. VB.NET is in maintenence mode and F# is filling a niche. But that's irrelevant about built-in libraries thing since all CIL assembly can interact with each other, so they call the same BCL. And what do you mean about different syntax?

Comment: Libraries do *not* dictate language syntax.  They are all capable of calling a procedure, the 1960s made sure.  The framework is heavily object-oriented, many languages are not, but that's pretty easy to hide.  The My namespace in vb.net is a good example of that.  If you want to dig in then look at the way they ported Cobol to .NET: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325177/is-there-actually-cobol-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both. All .Net languages have access to the BCL, but typically there is also some additional language-specific libraries to support common idioms in the language.

For example F# has the FSharp.Core library: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/ with support for F# specific types and utilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply buddy now it's clear to me.